# Can I create a TypeScript type where certain properties are an ID/array of IDs that can be expanded to reference other types

Tags: typescript

For context, in my database I have one-to-one and one-to-many relationships, which I'm trying to express in typescript. Instead of creating several variations of a type, I would like to create one type that allows me to **expand** relationships using utility types I'm creating (e.g. `ExpandOne<>`, `ExpandAll<>`).

[Simplified working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUBUEkBlpgUQMoCgAuBPADgU1NACKgC8oAzugE4CWAdgOaoY76IAe2AhnQCZcAjADa4APIjroaWAHykCxAD6gJUrMyx5QAYS5VRsULnbpcfcqB6YA2gF05ZQ8dPnQ1+gDNcVUAAlcXLwANKAAdOGe3qAA+ragAPx+AbygAFygdLgAbt4arDq8+k4mZrwWVnYOoMUuZW6RPtEh4aENoABKuJRxiZ2UaRnZuSxaHNx8APKZopBGJa6dAMYA9lS8opS0jCFWMiFjPCnOpeV0NnHKlfIA3qigbgDSuJig9KAA1s-LHqCQtumQaxPTBxY6uA58QQiURtVTSF5gupLVbrTb0Bg7M4yGR3e4JUDAua1Cy6fQQ3g4vF4xLkqZiOFYELaQriTiHbG4qnpNGMTkDQHA2yoAC+zBAvwmhAm6V0QiEKjZk0yoGWdFAAFsAK5CKTYESgbBUZZ4KhSLqocWaNiK3gAQTlYrAhFtkFtACFbchEL8AJoABRQzHopioHi4i3w4HIUVu9010aodC46tw3Oo6JFQck3jDEdAfuWlF0pgYqxesdAvC6i1o2CkqrTWyY9xrAXQq3S5KhYij3hxotQwZz4fwBf6FZW2ckjYzLa4JbLnZt3dEY-QxdwpaomH7jogyFtAHFEKhJ-1sIX0Evxrw6avLyFrAByRbzzdlp8hF9UNurJ-2G5hUsU5MFQC9KFCV8F23SCf3nVZQnjbwkxTIA)

**Spec**

*Everything I would like to have*

Is this even possible?

```js
// UTILITIES

type ID = string

type Expandable<Entity> = ID | Entity

type ExpandableArray<Entity> = undefined | Entity[]

type Car<L extends any[]> = L extends [infer Head, ...infer _] ? Head : never

type Cdr<L extends any[]> = L extends [infer _, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never

type ExpandOne<T extends Record<string, any>, Expand extends any[] | []> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Expandable<infer Entity extends Record<string, any>>
    ? Key extends Car<Expand>
      ? ExpandOne<Entity, Cdr<Expand>>
      : string
    : T[Key]
}

// TODO: Call ExpandOne on multiple properties
// type ExpandAll

// DATABASE TYPES

interface PostCategory {
  description: string
}

interface PostComment {
  content: string
}

interface Post {
  content: string
  comments: ExpandableArray<PostComment>
  category: Expandable<PostCategory>
}

interface User {
  username: string
  posts: Expandable<Post[]>
  comments: ExpandableArray<PostComment>
}

// USAGE
// expand one level deep
const expandedUserPost: ExpandOne<User, ['posts']> = {} as any
expandedUserPost.posts

// expand two levels deep
const expandedUserPostComments: ExpandOne<User, ['posts', 'comments']> = {} as any
expandedUserPostComments.posts[0].comments

// expand multiple
const expandMultiple: ExpandAll<User, [['posts', 'comments'], ['comments']]> = {} as any
expandMultiple.posts[0].comments
expandMultiple.comments

// bonus!
// would be nice if ExpandAll<> assumed that any Expandable<> that hasn't been expanded is a string (database id) and any ExpandableArray<> that hasn't been expanded is undefined
const expandNonePost: ExpandAll<Post, []> = {} as any
expandNonePost.category // type should be string

// NOTE
// Expandable<> is similar to ExpandableArray<> 
// except when something is not exapnded instead of being undefined its a database id (string)
const expandPost: ExpandOne<Post, ['category']> = {} as any
expandPost.category.description
```

**What I want to avoid**

```js
interface Posts {
  content: string
}

interface User {
  username: string
  posts: undefined
}

// I would prefer not to create multiple variations of each type
interface UserExpandedPosts {
  username: string
  posts: Posts[]
}
```

**The big picture**

```js
// Using this system I can create a JavaScript function that tells 
// my backend to expand relationships and my types at the same time

function fetchData(configFunction, expansions) {
  return fetch()
}

const data = await fetchData(getUser(), [['posts'], ['somethingElse']])

// Assuming the function getUser() has an expandable database type 
// associated with it, fetchData would know how to both ask my 
// backend to expand the entity as well as expanding matching TypeScript type 

// In other words as long as my expansion doesn't fail, the return type of
// fetchData would always match the data (including expansions I asked for)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// UTILITIES
declare const explandBrand: unique symbol

type Expandable<Entity> = string & { [explandBrand]: Entity }
//   

type Expand1<T, E extends string[]> =
  | T extends Expandable<infer X extends any[]> ? Expand1<X[number], E>[]
  : T extends Expandable<infer X> ? Expand1<X, E>
  : E extends [infer F extends keyof T, ...infer L extends string[]] ?
  | {
    [K in keyof T]: F extends K ? Expand1<T[K], L> : T[K]
  }
  : T;

type x1 = Expand1<User, ['posts']>
//   ^?

type x3 = Expand1<x1, ['comments']>
//   ^?

type x4 = Expand1<User, ['posts', 'comments']>
//   ^?


type Expand2<T, A extends string[][]> =
| A extends [infer F extends string[], ...infer L extends string[][]] ? Expand2<Expand1<T, F>, L>
: T

type x5 = Expand2<User, [['posts', 'comments'], ['comments']]>
//   ^?
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221130&ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=2#code/PTAEFUBUEkBlpgUQMoCgAmBTAxgGwIYBOmo2A9gHYDOALqJgB4AOBF6AQofmwFygCuFAJYBHfiSoBPALYAjMrlSoakpiUTNu6fLNyYAPIgo0hKgHygAvKFqEhFAOagAZKADeoANqMWWzloBdPiMTFVAAX1QQUBilFTVQDSYtAEZ9SAAaRPoGGkw2KhsaO0dPAItLVBiAH1BIHLyCxM02HT19ewAzTEJQAA0G-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-FenOdDIjE5DGEainFNCylsSZnHcbxroSUZlCNDQZlxlss4+sEkFIdBsH6NpNC6ZONB3EZQmYCJYleb2xz+QJ4WRZIdwqWpNmaY6vSGQIA4UPghquRZMQjsa0WIe0AXjO5emebyUEwfgcEBUF+nJUo5HgMgkYAOKIORPhaKAlAkHoABumC4KAWCbuBJD9WwmDoBlAUIWwmEGBlurFb65Hmko0RzegoA0AA7mQoCjeNhRTUwM05L2C1LQJ1VTit6Brf2TrDq6Uoeh586LjEy57WAB2gNI-C4CYLCYLdB0ALIQ1DeivZGuC4B9g5eF9o6-c9bo0qKf34wDu3kfIixUAAhORp0Q4dsgkMImlCP8Iao+jFj4FQVBLAtR0ABZCaAoy1Uh+gWDQgt0ILVAUCKdAM-kd1aHzQgjDmjigAAFNoNA6FzJBCOgACUwtsGb4khnVfkS1LoAy3LCsbm+B2q4UghYJ09gLbDdoAHJDct1hs2jcW0MKJNA+RfvoZAvXRFbYsWGrNhCNIQgEL0NBnYnei+Q14ugH1DA8XJoDHfzStUF6mCS9CmKFBQZB0Iw+BMPNh32LQmD4Idn4M-XHuYF7WGd8awuTUJ+uCpih1a3hxu+72QcYVhYc0DOCWiZI0p+kugZAA)

It is `string` for ids, for arrays it's also a `string` id, modify if you need that

Comment: Thanks! Thats much closer to what I'm trying to do, but I'm still struggling to create a utility that would allow me to pass multiple expansions `ExpandAll<User, [['posts', 'comments'], ['comments']]>`.  In this case, I think I need to take the results of two `Expand1<User, []>` types and merge them. So something like `Expand1 <User, ['posts', 'comments']> & Expand1 <User, ['comments']>`, but I know its more complicated then that. And ideally it work work with any number of expansions so I think it will need to be recursive. Does that make sense?

Comment: Here @ChristianJ

Comment: @ChristianJ if you want your arrays not to be strings, make them `typeof explandBrandArray & { [explandBrand]: Entity }`, then you won't be able to mix them with strings. Tho I honestly don't understand how will you fetch them if they are not strings. you cand & undefined with {} as that's never

Comment: Basically for one-to-one the entity value can be null, string, or the expanded entity. For one-to-many the entity value can be empty array or (when expanded) array of entities. Thats why I'm trying to decide if there should be a distinction between Expandable and Expandable Array.